# Azure Data Factory Incremental Load without altering on premises database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory to perform an incremental load on a database without using a watermark or change tracking technology. I do not have the rights to add watermarks to tables, I can only read data from the target database. The database system does not have an ability to enable change tracking technology. It is also a very large database, which is why I want to be able to incrementally load changes rather than dropping the entire database and re-uploading it every night.

Is there a way to only upload the changes without altering the on-premises database or am I SOL?

I am connecting to an old Sybase database on premises and uploading data to an Azure SQL Server Database.

Comment: Something has to tell you the change in your source.  So unless your source tables have some sort of last modified date or something you could use for the incremental load.   Or primary key, but that would only get you adds/deletes and not the changes.

Comment: That is what I suspected, thank you for confirming for me.

Comment: Hello @FRY-9C, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use Data Flow. It provide options 'upsert' for you to allow insert or update the data in Azure SQL database. We don't need to drop the entire database and re-uploading it every night.

[image]

Ref here : [Sink transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#sink-transformation)

Comment: Would upsert automatically detect the changes between the old table and the new table? If the database processes inserts, deletes, and updates, will dataflows automatically determine the deltas and then perform the same operations in the cloud?